# When reading a txt, It identifies two lines rather three lines

Tags: c++

Here I am trying to have getData read the contents of a text file and store each line of the file as a separate string element in a vector.

```
bool getData(const std::string& inputLocation, std::vector<std::string>& data)
{
    // TODO: Complete this function, and fix return value

    std::ifstream inputFile(inputLocation);

    if (!inputFile.is_open())
    {
        return false;
    }

    std::string line;

    while (std::getline(inputFile, line))
    {
        data.push_back(line);
    }

    inputFile.close();
    
    return true;
}
```

The given txt file is this:

```
YVOHJEZQLDITAUPKWBRCMXGNSF // first line
HELLOWORLD // second line
// Note that this is the third line with absolutely nothing in it.
```

The problem is that when I test if getData is working properly, it doesn't. The reason being is because getData should read three lines instead of two.

Comment: A line is a line. If you want to filter on content, that's what you'll need to do. No content - scrap it. See @JesperJuhl's comment below.

Comment: I see 5 lines in that input file - there are blank lines (that are still lines) between (and after) the ones containing text.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new tto stackoverflow. Please ignore the lines in between. First line is from the txt file is "YVOHJEZQLDITAUPKWBRCMXGNSF", the second line is HELLOWORLD" and the last (third) is blank.

Comment: probably that is because the `while` loop will check the last record and than it reaches the end of file try getting those data in another way maybe `std::getline(inputFile, line) while(!inputfile.eof()){        data.push_back(line); std::getline(inputFile, line) }` would work.

Comment: Ok, now it looks like what you described. There is an "empty" line last, right? Why isn't that part of the data you wish to process? Is it there by mistake?

Comment: I've edited for you.  let me know if that is what you actually have.

Comment: @TedLyngmo, yes. Someone above stated because of the while loop. I will check that.

Comment: @dm257 No, I mean in the actual file. Is there any unnecessary lines in the original file?

Comment: @Mahdy.n I strongly recommend reading [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition (i.e. `while (!stream.eof())`) considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/4581301) By reading a line ahead of the loop you avoid one of the common problems, but your suggestion will trip over a few of the less common ones. `while(std::getline(inputFile, line))` avoids just about all of the problems a read loop can run into.

Comment: Side note: that last `inputFile.close();` is redundant. The file will be automatically closed when `inputFile` goes out of scope at the end of the function.

Comment: @user4581301 Thanks for that, I know it's sometimes a problem, but I thought it would work for this type of code.

Comment: @Mahdy.n That's actually counter productive and totally against idiomatic and safe programming. Enter person with a relatively idiomatic way of solving these problems  and crisis arise.

Comment: When I used `istringstream ss{"line 1\nline 2\n\n"};` as the input, it read all 3 lines.

Answer (score 3):

If the 3rd line has no data, not even a line break, eg:

```
YVOHJEZQLDITAUPKWBRCMXGNSF<break>
HELLOWORLD<break>
```

Then there is technically *no 3rd line*, there is simply nothing left to read. `getline()` will set the `eofbit` flag when it encounters EOF, and set the `failbit` flag for trying to read when there is nothing available to read, thus breaking the loop.

If the 3rd line has no data but does have a line break, eg:

```
YVOHJEZQLDITAUPKWBRCMXGNSF<break>
HELLOWORLD<break>
<break>
```

Then there is something for `getline()` to read from the 3rd line. It will succeed, not set any flags yet, and return a blank string for the line. It will then fail as above when the next iteration tries to read a non-existent 4th line, breaking the loop.

If the 3rd line has data but no line break, eg:

```
YVOHJEZQLDITAUPKWBRCMXGNSF<break>
HELLOWORLD<break>
HI
```

Then there is something for `getline()` to read from the 3rd line. It will succeed, set the `eofbit` flag when it encounters EOF while reading the line, and return a non-empty string as expected.  It will then set the `failbit` flag as above when the next iteration tries to read a non-existent 4th line, breaking the loop.

[Online Demo](https://onlinegdb.com/NVKOJ-zKL)

Comment: If the 3rd line has no data, not even a line break, then *there is no 3rd line*.

Comment: @KeithThompson Sure, from a *technical* standpoint, but from a *user* perspective there is, because that is the way many text editors present it

Comment: That's unfortunate. If a file consists of `"line one\nline two\n"`, my editor (I use vim) shows two lines.

Comment: If there is data on the third line, followed immediately by end of file (no line break) then a fair number of unix programs actually discard any data they have read from the third line.

Comment: @Peter This is not true. They all read `1\n2\n3` into three lines 1, 2, 3.

Comment: @273K: Peter is correct.  Posix [defines](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap03.html) a _line_ as zero or more characters terminated by a newline.  If a text file does not end with a newline character, then it ends with what Posix defines as an _incomplete line_.  Some utility programs will ignore incomplete lines.  Famously, the line counting example in K&R counts newline characters and thus does not count an incomplete line at the end of a file.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Private K&R example is not a POSIX utility.

Comment: @273K A `sh` script with a loop of the form `while IFS= read -r line; do *process line* ; done` *discards* the last line of an input file without a newline immediately before EOF.  This is due to the POSIX  specification of how the `read` built-in works. It can cause head-scratching (say, editing the last line in a way expected to affect processing results/output) since text editors (typically, by default) display that last line with no indication of a missing newline and also won't add a newline if the file is edited. [Recent versions of *some* text editors do give a warning].

Comment: @273K:  I didn't mean to suggest that the K&R example was a Posix utility.  It is a well-known example of the common practice of ignoring an incomplete line.  The K&R line counter yields the same result as `wc -l` when the input ends with an incomplete line.

Comment: @Peter I see, tested it, your are right.